# java generics subtype list and method error

Tags: java, generics

Java generics

I am new to generics trying have list which accepts child of A as a parameter.

i wrote following code, there is a error on the bottom of question. any help is appreciated.

```
abstract class A{
..
}

class A1 extends A{
..
}
class A2 extends A{
..
}
```

i want to declare a list

```
public class Model{
    private List<? extends A> items;

    public <S extends A> void add(S item){
      items.add(item); // error on this line
    }
}
```

[image]
i gets a compile time error on add method saying add(S) in list cannot be applied to (S)

Comment: Which class is the code at the bottom in?

Comment: i updated my question, for example Model class is is at the bottom

Comment: On which line does the error occur? I think you're missing a part of the code. [I cannot reproduce it](https://ideone.com/Ng6dnV). Are you trying to add the input item to the list?

Comment: Are you trying to do `items.add(item)` in `Model::add`?

Comment: i am getting compile time error on method declaration of add(S item)

Comment: But what is your code in that method? Do you try to add to `items`?

Comment: Copy-paste your code into a new file and you'll see there's no error.

Comment: i have not write any thing in this method it is already giving me compile time error on method declration on <S extends A> void add(S item)

Comment: The code as given shows no error. Something is missing that is actually causing the error. The message you have given suggests that you are trying to either do something within this method or trying to call it from somewhere else; could you show us your full code as a MCVE please?

Comment: you are correct sorry error is when i am trying to add an item into the list let me update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because **generics are invariant**.

```
private List<? extends A> items;

public <S extends A> void add(S item) {
    items.add(item);
}
```

With `<? extends A>` it doesn't mean *"any subtype of `A`"*, but you actually say ***"an unknown type that is a subtype of `A`"*** (or `A` itself). You are trying to add an item of type `S` to the list, but `S` can be a different type than the unknown type.

### Analogy

Let me explain it by the following analogy. The bottom line is: a `Cat` is an `Animal`, a `Dog` is an `Animal` as well, but a `Cat` is *not* a `Dog`.

Suppose I have a list with `<? extends Animal>`. That could be a list of `Dog`s, but it could also be a list of `Cat`s, or `Bird`s, or any type that is a subtype of `Animal`. Whatever. We just don't care.

Then what do we have here?

```
public <S extends Animal> void add(S item) {
    this.items.add(item);
}
```

`S` is a certain subtype of `Animal`, but the compiler doesn't know which type. It could be that `items` contains only `Bird`s and we are trying to add a `Cat`. **Adding a cat to a list of birds means trouble, isn't it?** The type parameter of `items` is simply unknown. We simply cannot add a `Cat` to a list of `Dog`s, hence the error.

---

### What to do about it?

Simply remove the wildcard...

```
List<A> items;

public void add(A item) {
    this.items.add(item);
}
```

...or make the class generic:

```
class Model<T> {

    List<T> items;

    public void add(T item) {
        this.items.add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, you explained very well i don't know any reason to mark this question as negative :(

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use the following syntax instead of generics?

```
public class Model
{
    private List<A> items ;

    public void add(A item)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: That is generics.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to avoid annotations like that "<? extends A>" and use only the reference to the abstract class "<A>" ;)

Comment: This does not answer the question.